Move from a flow to another one in Flowerjs
How can I go from a node in Flower flow "A" to a specific node in Flower flow "B" or any other flow?
I tried the following, but it doesn’t seem to work.
(I’m inside a Flower flow called “partners” and I want to move to a node inside the "events" flow):
import { useEffect } from ‘react’
import {  Loader } from ‘@components
import {  useFlower } from '@flowerforce/flower-react'
 
const NavigateToEvents = () => {
const { jump } = useFlower({ flowName: "events" })
useEffect(() =>  jump("eventDetail"), [jump])
return <Loader/>
}

Basically I'm running in a flow but, at certain point based on user choice, I need to stop this flow and continue in another one.
Example
For example, in the image we have 2 flow.
In a standard situation I'll move from point A to point D or from point Z to point K but, in my case, I need to start from Point A and, then, move to point Y.
There is a way to do that?

In this way, it's not possible to navigate from one flow to another one. By calling the jump("eventDetail") method, you're modifying the current flow's history, setting the node with the id "eventDetail" as the current node, but this doesn't change the displayed flow.
Assuming you have two flows, A and B, and you want to move from flow A to flow B starting from a specific node, there are two possible solutions:

Change the rendered component. For example, assuming flows A and B contain two different pages, you can achieve this through a route change.
Insert a node in flow A that contains a SubFlow, which references flow B. At this point, to switch from flow A to flow B, it's enough to navigate to the node containing the SubFlow.

The startId prop of the Flower component allows us to define the specific node from which the flow should begin.
